# Default to Folder View in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

By default, Visual Studio 2022 does not show any of the project files or folders. It opens a nearly useless view of all of the "projects" in a solution.

[image: Screenshot of default Solution Explorer]

Instead, I would like for it to default to the "Folder View," which shows all of the relevant files associated with the project:

[image: Screenshot of Folder View]

It is annoying to have to manually switch to the Folder View every time I open a project. Is there any way to make this the default?

Alternatively, is there any way to suppress extraneous "projects" in the default view such that only the important information is visible?

Comment: Not blaming you - Unity specific that would probably be desired most of the time ... just fyi the solutions view including all solutions makes much more sense to be the default for almost all other types of .NET applications ;) I'm sure you somewhere can set the default windows to be opened .. e.g. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2018/08/Controlling-Default-Window-Layout.aspx

Comment: Why not 'open a local folder' rather than 'a project or solution' then VS will open with the folder view.